# Scraping Numbers from HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have the question of reading the HTML from the data files, and parse the data, extracting numbers and compute the sum of the numbers in the file.

Here is the code

```
from BeautifulSoup import *
    import socket

    mysock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mysock.connect(('python-data.dr-chuck.net',80))

    mysock.send('GET http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html HTTP/1.0\n\n')
    while True:
        data = mysock.recv(512000)
        if ( len(data) < 1 ) :
            break
        print data
    mysock.close()
    data2=BeautifulSoup(data)

    tags=data2('a')
    sum=0
    for line in tags:
        a=line.get('span',None)
        sum+=int(a.text)
    print sum
```

But I am getting following error

```
C:\Users\Dhruv>miscbeautifulsoup.py
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sun, 26 Jun 2016 05:14:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 177
Connection: close
Server: -nginx
CF-RAY: -

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error and although I have used HTTP 1.0 in error it is mentioned HTTP 1.1
 please help me in understanding my error code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using sockets instead of [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line

```
mysock.send('GET http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

to

```
mysock.send('GET /comments_42.html HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

I took a look at a request from this page and in the source request the page was requested like this.

```
GET /quant.js HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send some headers when you get `/comments_42.html` making sure to set accept to `utf-8/ascii` so you get text back:

```
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('python-data.dr-chuck.net', 80))
mysock.send('''GET /comments_42.html HTTP/1.1
 Accept-Encoding:utf-8
Host:python-data.dr-chuck.net
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36.0\r\n\r\n
''')
```

`Accept-Encoding:utf-8` and `Host:python-data.dr-chuck.net` are essential for the request to work, the u-a is optional but usually a good idea.

The full working code, using `bs4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('python-data.dr-chuck.net', 80))
mysock.send('''GET /comments_42.html HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding:utf-8
Host:python-data.dr-chuck.net\r\n\r\n
''')
html = ""
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(1000)
    html += data
    if data.endswith("\r\n\r\n"):
        break

mysock.close()
data2 = BeautifulSoup(html)
sm = sum(int(s.text) for s in  data2.select("span.comments"))
print(sm)
```

Which gives you:

```
2553
```

The response headers and the body are in the html, I will leave it to yourself to figure out separating them.

Answer (score -1):

This will sum up all the numbers under comments column:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

link = "http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html"

reuest = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reuest.text,"lxml")

soupl=soup.findAll("span", { "class" : "comments" })
sum=0

for item in soupl:
    sum = sum + int(item.text)

print(sum)
```